# Remove a randomly selected array from a list during a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, simulation

I'm currently trying to develop a kind of simulation game based of Counter Strike for fun and studies.

**What I did:**
I've created objects to each player, then I put them into an array for their respective teams, then I simulate some duels (randomly selecting which players face who in each round) with results based on their stats (previously declared in their objects properties_.

**What I'm trying to do is:**
Whenever someone wins a duel, I want them to be removed from the "round" to not have them repeatedly dueling after they "died".

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    getConsole = document.querySelector(".console");
    setTimeout( function timer(){
        getConsole.insertAdjacentHTML ("beforebegin", "<p>Round: " + rounds + "</p>" );
        calculateAim();
        rounds++
        console.log('rounds ' + rounds) }, i * 3000 );
    };
} 


function calculateAim() {

    for ( var r = 0; r < 5; r++ ) {
        getConsole = document.querySelector(".console");
        let playerTeam = [player1, player2, player3]
        let enemyTeam = [player4, player5, player6],

        battle1 = playerTeam[Math.floor(Math.random() * playerTeam.length)];
        battle2 = enemyTeam[Math.floor(Math.random() * enemyTeam.length)];
        console.log("Player Team: " + battle1)
        console.log("Enemy Team: " + battle2)

        let min1 = 0; 
        let max2 = 100;  
        let EncounterRating = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max2 - +min1)) + +min1; 
        if (EncounterRating < 5) {
            getConsole.insertAdjacentHTML ("beforebegin", "The bomb has exploded and CT's saved their weapons. <br>");
            break;
        }

        else {

            if (battle1.aim > battle2.aim) {
                getConsole.insertAdjacentHTML ("beforebegin", battle1.name + " killed " + battle2.name + " because your aim is " + battle1.aim + " and his enemie's is " + battle2.aim + " <br>");
            } 

            if (battle1.aim < battle2.aim) {
                getConsole.insertAdjacentHTML ("beforebegin",  battle2.name + " killed " + battle1.name  + " because your aim is " + battle2.aim + " and his enemie's is " + battle1.aim + " <br>");
            }

            if (battle1.aim == battle2.aim && battle1.luck > battle2.luck) {
                getConsole.insertAdjacentHTML ("beforebegin", battle1.name + " killed " + battle2.name + " with a lucky shot<br>");
            }   

            if (battle1.aim == battle2.aim && battle2.luck > battle1.luck) {
                getConsole.insertAdjacentHTML ("beforebegin", battle2.name + " killed " + battle1.name + " with a lucky timing<br>");
            }  

        } 
    }
```

What I am getting with this code is even if they have lost the duel based on the result of the tests, they will continue in the "round".

Comment: you can remove an element at index i from array with `array.splice(i, 1)`

Comment: Your braces are not matching properly. You have an extra `}` after the first `for` loop, and you have no ending `}` for `function calculateAim()`

Comment: You should also declare `battle2` with `let`, you're making it a global variable.

Comment: These problems become obvious when you use an editor's automatic indentation feature.

Comment: @Barmar the code is missing its first part, i'm sorry, but is just a for loop. thats why the } is there. Its working just fine, i'm just looking for the logic behind what i want to do.

Comment: It appears as though, in each iteration of the loop within `calculateAim()`, you re-add players to a team. I would add a flag to the player `isDead` and set it to true when the player dies. Then, when you're creating your team, you don't add them to a team if `isDead` is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way to go about this would probably be to have a function to compare selected players from each team, remove the player that loses using `.splice()`, and re-provide the new, smaller arrays to the same function using recursion.

```js
const getConsole = document.querySelector(".console");
let rounds = 1

const player1 = { name: 'Paul', aim: 1, luck: 6 },
  player2 = { name: 'Jim', aim: 2, luck: 5 },
  player3 = { name: 'Sally', aim: 3, luck: 4 },
  player4 = { name: 'Laura', aim: 4, luck: 3 },
  player5 = { name: 'Jim II', aim: 5, luck: 2 },
  player6 = { name: 'Karen', aim: 6, luck: 1 }
  
getConsole.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<p>Begin battle</p>");

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function timer() {
    getConsole.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<p>Round: " + rounds + "</p>");
    battleHelper();
    rounds++
    console.log('rounds ' + rounds)
  }, i * 3000);
}


function battleHelper() {
  let playerTeam = [player1, player2, player3]
  let enemyTeam = [player4, player5, player6]
  
  battle(playerTeam, enemyTeam);
}

function battle(playerTeam, enemyTeam) { 
  // If either of the teams have no members, end the round
  if (!playerTeam.length || !enemyTeam.length) {
    return;
  }
  
  // Duplicate the input teams to modify them
  let playerTeamOutput = playerTeam
  let enemyTeamOutput = enemyTeam
  
  // Get the index for a random player from each team
  playerTeamIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * playerTeamOutput.length)
  enemyTeamIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * enemyTeamOutput.length)
  
  // Get the player from each team
  player = playerTeam[playerTeamIndex];
  enemy = enemyTeam[enemyTeamIndex];
  console.log("Player Team: " + player.name)
  console.log("Enemy Team: " + enemy.name)
  
  let min1 = 0;
  let max2 = 100;
  
  let EncounterRating = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max2 - +min1)) + +min1;
  if (EncounterRating < 5) {
    getConsole.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "The bomb has exploded and CT's saved their weapons. <br>");
    // If the bomb is detonated, end the round
    return;
  } else {
    if (player.aim > enemy.aim) {
      getConsole.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", player.name + " killed " + enemy.name + " because your aim is " + player.aim + " and his enemie's is " +enemy.aim + " <br>");
      enemyTeamOutput.splice(enemyTeamIndex, 1)
    
    } else if (player.aim < enemy.aim) {
      getConsole.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", enemy.name + " killed " + player.name + " because your aim is " + enemy.aim + " and his enemie's is " + player.aim + " <br>");
      playerTeamOutput.splice(playerTeamIndex, 1)
    
    } else if (player.aim == enemy.aim && player.luck > enemy.luck) {
      getConsole.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", player.name + " killed " + enemy.name + " with a lucky shot<br>");
      enemyTeamOutput.splice(enemyTeamIndex, 1)
    
    } else if (player.aim == enemy.aim && enemy.luck > player.luck) {
      getConsole.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", battle2.name + " killed " + player.name + " with a lucky timing<br>");
      playerTeamOutput.splice(playerTeamIndex, 1)
    }
  }
  
  console.log(`Player Size: ${playerTeamOutput.length}`)
  console.log(`Enemy Size: ${enemyTeamOutput.length}`)
  
  // Immedietly recall the function to begin another battle
  return battle(playerTeamOutput, enemyTeamOutput)
}
```

```html
<div class="console"></div>
```

Thanks for posting and let me know if you would like me to explain anything I did further!

Comment: I will try that as soon as possible, but thank you so much for your time and help sir.